# How to redirect to a URL with a query parameter after sign in with google?

Tags: url, redirect, parameters

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import '@fontsource-variable/dancing-script';
import {
  Box,
  HStack,
  Flex,
  Text,
  Button,
  Alert,
  AlertIcon,
  Link,
  VStack,
  Heading,
  ChakraProvider,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import Image from "next/image";
import theme from "../components/theme";
import GuestMenuBar from "../components/guestMenuBar.js";
import GetLoginID from "../components/GetLoginID";

import { useRouter } from "next/router";
// for Firestore database
import {
  collection,
  addDoc,
  getDoc,
  getDocs,
  query,
  where,
  doc,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { firestore, auth } from "./firebase.js";
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
// for Firestore database

export default function guestMainPage() {
  // for Firestore database
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const router = useRouter();
  const { eventName, rsvpComplete, rsvpSubmitted, rsvpEditSubmitted } = router.query;
  const loginID = GetLoginID();
  const [showRSVPNotification, setShowRSVPNotification] = useState(false);
  const [showEditRSVPNotification, setShowEditRSVPNotification] = useState(false);
  // State to store event details
  const [eventDetails, setEventDetails] = useState({
    // Initialize fields with empty values
    eventName: "",
    eventDesc: "",
    placeName: "",
    address: "",
    addInfo: "",
    photoLink: "",
    contact1: "",
    phone1: "",
    contact2: "",
    phone2: "",
    selectedRSVPdate: "",
    startTime: "",
    endTime: "",
    selectedFile: "",
    itinerary: [],
  });

   // Fetch event details from Firestore
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchEventDetails = async () => {
      try {
        // Go thru the path into EventCreated
        const userDocRef = doc(
          collection(firestore, "eventOwner_uid"),
          loginID
        );
        const eventCreatedCollectionRef = collection(
          userDocRef,
          "EventCreated"
        );
        // Get the doc with matching eventName
        const q = query(
          eventCreatedCollectionRef,
          where("eventName", "==", eventName)
        );
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
        querySnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
          const eventDoc = await getDoc(doc.ref);
          if (eventDoc.exists()) {
            const data = eventDoc.data();

            setEventDetails({
              ...data,
              selectedRSVPdate: data.rsvpDate,
              selectedFile: data.qrCodeImageURL,
            });
          }
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching event details: ", error);
      }
    };

    if (loginID && eventName) {
      fetchEventDetails();
    }
  }, [loginID, eventName]);


  // Push 'Attendee' and 'Edit' buttons
  const handleLinkClick = (url) => {
    router.push(url); // Navigate to the specified URL
  };

  // Use useEffect to check the query parameter and set the state accordingly
  useEffect(() => {
    if (rsvpSubmitted === "true") {
      setShowRSVPNotification(true);
    }
  }, [rsvpSubmitted]);

  // Use useEffect to check the query parameter and set the state accordingly
  useEffect(() => {
    if (rsvpEditSubmitted === "true") {
      setShowEditRSVPNotification(true);
    }
  }, [rsvpEditSubmitted]);

  return (
    <>
    {/* {auth.currentUser && ( */}
        <VStack spacing={4} bg="#EFDBDA" align="stretch">
          <GuestMenuBar />
          <Flex bg="#EFDBDA" alignItems="center" flexDirection="column" h="130vh">
            <Box
                bgImage="url('/flower.jpg')"
                bgPosition="center"
                bgRepeat="no-repeat"
                boxShadow="sm"
                borderRadius="md"
                p={310}
                w="100%"
                h="130vh"
                pl={350}
            >
              <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
                <Box textAlign="center" fontWeight="bold" fontSize="2xl">
                    <Heading color="#8B4513">Welcome to Attend</Heading>
                </Box>
              </ChakraProvider>

                <Flex mt={5} alignItems="center" justifyContent="center">
                    <Image src="/specialLine.png" alt="My Image" width={500} height={300} />
                </Flex>
              
              <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
                <Box textAlign="center" fontWeight="bold" fontSize="2xl">
                    <Heading color="#8B4513">{eventDetails.eventName}</Heading>
                </Box>
              </ChakraProvider>

                <Flex mt={5} alignItems="center" justifyContent="center">
                    <Image src="/specialLine.png" alt="My Image" width={500} height={300} />
                </Flex>

            <HStack mb={5} display="flex" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
              <Link onClick={() => handleLinkClick(`/guestRSVP?eventName=${eventName}`)}>
                <Button
                  size="lg"
                  colorScheme="yellow"
                  variant="solid"
                  ml={10}
                  mt={10}
                  bg="#550E0B"
                  _hover={{ bg: "#450A07" }}
                  isDisabled={rsvpComplete === "true"}
                >
                  <Text color="white" fontSize="1xl" fontWeight="bold">RSVP Form</Text>
                </Button>
              </Link>

              <Link onClick={() => handleLinkClick(`/guestEditRSVP?eventName=${eventName}`)}>
                <Button
                  size="lg"
                  colorScheme="yellow"
                  variant="solid"
                  ml={10}
                  mt={10}
                  bg="#550E0B"
                  _hover={{ bg: "#450A07" }}
                >
                  <Text color="white" fontSize="1xl" fontWeight="bold">Edit RSVP</Text>
                </Button>
              </Link>

              <Link onClick={() => handleLinkClick(`/guestFeedback?eventName=${eventName}`)}>
                <Button
                  size="lg"
                  colorScheme="yellow"
                  variant="solid"
                  ml={10}
                  mt={10}
                  bg="#550E0B"
                  _hover={{ bg: "#450A07" }}
                >
                  <Text color="white" fontSize="1xl" fontWeight="bold">Feedback</Text>
                </Button>
              </Link>
          </HStack>

          {showRSVPNotification && (
            <Alert status="success" variant='left-accent'>
              <AlertIcon />
              RSVP Form Submitted!
            </Alert>
          )}

          {showEditRSVPNotification && (
            <Alert status="success" variant='left-accent'>
              <AlertIcon />
              RSVP Form Edited!
            </Alert>
          )}

            </Box>
          </Flex>
          <Text variant="body2" color="text.secondary" textAlign="center">
            {"Copyright © "}
            <Link color="inherit" href=" ">
              HappyFam
            </Link>{" "}
            {new Date().getFullYear()}
            {"."}
          </Text>
        </VStack>
        {/* )} */}
    </>
  );
}
```

```js
import {
    Flex,
    Box,
    Button,
    Text,
    Link,
    Input,
    InputGroup,
    InputRightElement,
    Image,
    FormControl,
    Heading,
    Center,
  } from "@chakra-ui/react";
  import { ViewIcon, ViewOffIcon } from "@chakra-ui/icons";
  import { FcGoogle } from 'react-icons/fc'
  import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
  import router from "next/router";
  // Import to use firebase
  import { firestore, auth } from "./firebase";
  import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
  
  
  function guestLoginPage() {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);
    const [url, setUrl] = useState(null);

     // Google OAuth URL
      useEffect(() => {
        // Fetch the URL from your API
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/guestOauth")
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            setUrl(data);
          });
      }, []);
  
    // Login function for email and password
    const handleLogin = async () => {
      try {
        const resultEmail = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          auth,
          email,
          password
        );
  
        if (resultEmail) {
          router.push(`/guestMainPage?eventName=${eventName}`);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
  
    return (
      <>
        <Flex bg="#EFDBDA" alignItems="center" flexDirection="column" h="95.4vh">
          <Flex
            bg="#EFDBDA"
            justifyContent="center"
            alignItems="center"
            flexDirection="column"
            mt="5"
            mb="5"
          >
            <Image src="/logo.png" alt="Home Image" w="80%" h="auto" />
          </Flex>
          <Box
            bg="white"
            opacity={0.8}
            boxShadow="sm"
            borderRadius="md"
            pt={6}
            pl={10}
            pr={10}
            w="25%"
            h="45%"
            mb="5"
            textAlign="center"
          >
            <Heading as="h2" size="md" mb={6}>
              Guest LogIn
            </Heading>
            <FormControl>
              <Input
                type="email"
                value={email}
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                placeholder="Email"
              />
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl mt={4} id="password" isRequired>
            <InputGroup>
              <Input
                type={showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
                value={password}
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                placeholder="Password"
              />
              <InputRightElement h={"full"}>
                    <Button
                      variant={"ghost"}
                      onClick={() =>
                        setShowPassword((showPassword) => !showPassword)
                      }
                    >
                      {showPassword ? <ViewIcon /> : <ViewOffIcon />}
                    </Button>
              </InputRightElement>
              </InputGroup>
            </FormControl>
            <Button mt={12} onClick={handleLogin}>
              Log In
            </Button>
            <Text mt={4} color="grey" fontSize="sm">
              Don't have an account?{" "}
              <Link href="/guestSignUpPage" textDecoration="underline">
                Sign up
              </Link>
            </Text>
          </Box>

          {/* Google */}
        <Button bg="white" w="12%" variant={'outline'} leftIcon={<FcGoogle />} onClick={() => (window.location.href = url)}>
          <Center>
            <Text>Sign in with Google</Text>
          </Center>
        </Button>
  
        </Flex>
  
        <Flex
          bg="#EFDBDA"
          justifyContent="center" //center horizontally
          alignItems="center" //center vertically
          flexDirection="column"
        >
          <Text mb="3" fontSize="sm" color="gray.500">
            ©2023 by HappyFam
          </Text>
        </Flex>
      </>
    );
  }
  export default guestLoginPage;
```

```js
import { google } from "googleapis";
import { serialize } from "cookie";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export default async function guestOauthCallback(req, res) {
  // Set up the OAuth Client
  const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    "32187185522-mm51fqea2ne4p6huotk81qrbuj3mfkmp.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "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",
    ["http://localhost:3000/api/guestOauthCallback"]
  );

  // Get the authorization code from the query parameters
  const authorizationCode = req.query.code;

  if (!authorizationCode) {
    res.status(400).send("Missing or invalid authorization code");
    return;
  }

  // Get access token, refresh token and ID token from the authorization code
  try {
    const { tokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken(authorizationCode);
    const tokenData = {
      accessToken: tokens.access_token,
      refreshToken: tokens.refresh_token,
      decodedIDToken: jwt.decode(tokens.id_token),
    };


    // Store the tokenData in a cookie (client-side)
    res.setHeader(
      "Set-Cookie",
      serialize("tokens", JSON.stringify(tokenData), {
        //httpOnly: true, // Only accessible from server side
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, // 1 week
      })
    ); 

    // Redirect to the guestMainPage
    res.redirect(`/guestMainPage`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error exchanging authorization code for tokens:", error);
    res.status(500).send("Error exchanging authorization code for tokens");
  }
}
```

I want user to redirect to /guestMainPage?eventName=${eventName} after the user sign in with Google successfully. How can I make it?

I had tried to add on "eventName = req.query.eventName;" in my guestOauthCallback.js, but it still unsuccessful, it cannot pops out the specific event name and the eventName is undefined. `